# renaming files in different folders

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, rename

i have  1000 folders and each folders contain  5 files with same name that i want to copy and rename in different name.

For example:

My folders path

```
/home/yuan/data/foldera1/*
/home/yuan/data/foldera2/*
/home/yuan/data/foldera3/*
/home/yuan/data/foldera4/*
.........................
/home/yuan/data/foldera1000/*
```

And the files i want to rename is

```
data1.ax.ze  to  data.a1.z1
datay.ax.z1  to  data.a2.z2
dataw.ac.zt  to  data.a3.z3
data4.an.z5  to  data.a4.z4
datax.aa.zq  to  data.a5.z5
```

i tried script below: but it doesnot rename files inside each folder

```
for file in /home/yuan/data/foldera?/*
do
cp data1.ax.ze    data.a1.z1
cp datay.ax.z1    data.a2.z2
cp dataw.ac.zt    data.a3.z3
cp data4.an.z5    data.a4.z4
cp datax.aa.zq    data.a5.z5
done
```

Hope experts will help me solving this problem.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
for dir in /home/yuan/data/foldera*; do
  cd "$dir"
  cp data1.ax.ze    data.a1.z1
  cp datay.ax.z1    data.a2.z2
  cp dataw.ac.zt    data.a3.z3
  cp data4.an.z5    data.a4.z4
  cp datax.aa.zq    data.a5.z5
done
```